# Xcode7 - Swift App - run sudo command with higher privileges

Tags: swift, sudo, xcode7, sudoers

I have compose and application which repairs disks via "fsck_hfs". 
I would like to make it available for others, but because of the sudo command, it is reporting an error when I try to run it on another account. I need to implement something (like askpass?) to have higher privileges (only for the sudo command)

Here is the code :

```
    let trait2 = "/dev/disk2s2"

    // sudo
    let sudo : NSTask = NSTask()
    sudo.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sudo"
    sudo.arguments = [ "fsck_hfs","-dfr",trait2 ]
    sudo.launch()
    sudo.waitUntilExit()
```

I have setup sudoers on my account so it work but if I try with another user, I get the following error message :

```
    Unable to open block device /dev/disk2s2: Permission denied
```

What should I do to make this app available to others without them needing to do anything else then typing their password?

Thanks